# Installing ArcGIS Web Adaptor without Windows Authentication?

Tags: authentication, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-web-adaptor

Is is possible to install ArcGIS Web Adaptor without Windows Authentication? I am installing ArcGIS Web Adaptor for Server and Portal. I need to enable ISS components and I realized that I do not have Windows Authentication. I am using Windows 10 Home edition. How should I go about installing Web Adaptor as the installer will not let me proceed without enabling all the ISS components requirements.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use IIS? How about switching to tomcat (e.g) ? http://server.arcgis.com/en/web-adaptor/latest/install/java-windows/install-arcgis-web-adaptor-server.htm

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Home edition doesn't include Windows Authentication (and a bunch of other IIS security features). However, the package with these features is sitting right there in your OS and you can manually install it.

All you need to do is open an elevated command prompt and run:

> dism /online /norestart /add-package:%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum

Filename above may be slightly different since it's based on your system's bitness and version

Then just make your way back to:

> Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Security

All the "pro" options under Security will be available. Simply check "Windows Authentication" and reboot.

Comment: With an entire copy paste like this, you could at least link [your source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197001/1203116)

Answer (score 0):

No.
ArcGIS Web Adaptor requires some IIS components.
Look at the documentation [Enabling IIS and required IIS components](http://server.arcgis.com/en/web-adaptor/latest/install/iis/enable-iis-8-components-server.htm)

Comment: Unless you want to go with a linux stack, in which case IIS is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As ylka points out, IIS is not necessary per se, but in order to run ArcGIS Server you, uh, need a server.  Now I suppose that you *could* try and use any old server stack you like and try to hack ArcGIS into it, but I suspect that this isn't exactly your speed.  ylka proffers Tomcat, but if you're happiest in Windows World then you can use [IIS Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264) fo free.